# I don't know why navbar text color is not changing for my code?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the navbar using bootstrap and CSS. I tried many ways but to change the navbar text color, but none of any way is working except inline CSS. Anyone can help me in resolving my issue.

```html
<!DOCType html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Second Class Assignment</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="image/logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Learn Xpert">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PAGES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-blue" href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-blue" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  </nav>

  <!---JavaScript--->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS File

```
/* CSS */ 
a{
    color:#ff6347;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Inspect the element in browser and find out which rule is getting applied to the element/nav. it should be some bootstrap rule. copy that rule and paste in your style sheet and apply style.

Comment: @Zim I tried these ways but not found a good one for me.

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap styles navlinks with

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

So to override, you would need the same level of specificity (or higher) included after the original style.  A bare anchor style is not specific enough to change the style of your links which is why your colour does not change

[More information about css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks. To everyone. It's working. :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors have specificity. You should avoid using the `!important` directive, because it makes your code difficult to maintain and scale.

Instead, you need to add equivalent or more specificity to your selector:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item a.nav-link {
  color: #ff6347;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To everyone. It's working. :)

Answer (score 1):

Target this way

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:#ff6347;
    font-size: 20px;;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/xda1sur5/3/

Comment: Thanks. To everyone. It's working. :)